# Python. Поиск частичного совпадения с последующим созданием индекса

Tags: python, функции, поиск, индексы

Необходимо изменить параметры функции, которая выполняет точный поиск заданного ключевого слова в текстовом файле, для частичного поиска с присвоением индекса. Например имеется ключевое слово "на" и необходимо выделить индекс всех слов, которые начинаются на эту приставку, к примеру слово "надо". Вот код функции с точным поиском:

```py
def create_index(self): 

 indexes = {} 

 keywords =self.get_keyword_list()
 
 for kw in keywords: 

 indexes[kw] = {} 

 for file in self.get_file_list(self.get_dir_list()): 

 file_text = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') 

 clean_file = re.sub(r'[^А-Яа-я0-9\n ]+', '', file_text.read()) 

 for i, word in 
enumerate(clean_file.split()): 

 if word in keywords: 

 if file not in indexes[word]: 

 indexes[word][file] = [] 

 indexes[word][file].append(i) 

 file_text.close() 

 with open('index.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as index_file: 
 index_file.write(json.dumps(indexes, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2))
 
 index_file.close()
```

Comment: Я вам сделал выделение блока кода, а вы сделайте теперь нормальные отступы

Comment: почему не использовать рекурсивный вызов `string.find(str,start,stop)`?

Comment: ganz, если я правильно помню предложенный вами метод присваивает каждому символу в файле индекс, а мне нужно чтобы само слово выделялось как индекс.